# PHP/MySQL How to Trigger a SMS or Mail to customer

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new in using - **PHP-Codeigniter 2.1.3, MySQL , XAMPP**. I have a Database tables  `Customer`, While new customer interested into the table, I want that immediately to sent a **mail or SMS** to his phone.

I tried the following code, In MySQL table I added a trigger with `customer` table, In that trigger I wanted to assign my php file or CONTROLLER Path to sent mail, but showing errors.

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.flag = 1 THEN
   DECLARE result CHAR(255);
   SET cmd = CONCAT('E:/xampp/php/php.exe -f "E:/xampp/htdocs/DEN/sentMail.php"');
END IF;
END
```

How can I solve this issue, is there any other easy way please...!! I am highly expecting your idea and kind support. Thanking you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good solution because it is strictly operating for that system paths.

I have 2 solutions on the top of my head that I am using in my current project.

1. Not really sure about CI but you can use the event/observer/subscriber w/e pattern. So anywhere in your code that a customer gets created an event `CustomerCreated($customer)` gets fired. Then a `sendMail` handler can be triggered on that event. This way you can have multiple channels for a customer to get created and the `sendMail` handler can be attached to multiple events as well.
2. On top of that solution another practice has served me well. Because an email is a relatively slow action to complete, you can build an `emails` table in your database, something like (`id, from, to, type_id, status, sent_at, to_be_sent_at`) and then make a script that gets all emails where `to_be_sent_at < now() and sent_at is not null` (or `status <> whatever`), distributes the email, updates `status` and `sent_at`. You can then setup a cron job to execute this script every x minutes. This way at any place in your code you can just add to this table and you know that the email will be distributed at the given time. Easy to debug when you have the table.

Also have a look at [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126752/how-to-execute-system-command-in-mysql-stored-procedure) to see why your code doesn't work.

I remember there is a mysql extension that provides this functionality, however I highly doubt this is a good practice. You will become highly dependent on your database, where from my pov it should be quite the oposite.

Hope you find this useful,

Cheers

Comment: Dear Donii, Thank you for your kind advise. But the customer Event would not be created. Because The value would be inserted from another DB table. I did something, But i am getting some Error Message, If you have any advise on this, To use this UDF functions, Should i install any additional software or anything like this .....!!!

Comment: Its showing this error. 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1305

FUNCTION cen_db.sys_exec does not exist

Filename: E:\xampp\htdocs\CEN\main\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330